# Update Google Sheets Script - Add cell notes to heat map table

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheets Script process that copies the required row, column and DBH data to a heat map table.  See first screenshot and the partial answer, [Copy data to a heat map table with Cell notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77883737/google-sheets-script-copy-data-to-a-heat-map-table-with-cell-notes).  How would this process be updated to dynamically add the ID, DBH **and other potential data fields** to the related cell notes per the second screenshot cell note example?

[image]

[image]

I have updated the TheWizEd's answer to include variable substitution and usage comments.  Great job!

```
function test1() {
  try {
    //  Required data sheet column order: Row, Column,  DBH, ID, OptionalColumn1, etc
    let MY_LAST_COL = 4;  // Enter your last data sheet column number
    let MY_ROWS_COLUMNS_TEXT = 6; // Enter your heat map column number that you want to contain the text: "Rows & Columns"
    let MY_ROWS_COLUMNS_NBR = 7; // Enter your heat map column number that will start the set of column numbers
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("mysitenotes"); // Enter the name of your target worksheet
    //let values = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,4).getValues();  // exclude header
      let values = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,MY_LAST_COL).getValues();  // exclude header
    let rows = values.map( row => row[0] );  // get the row numbers
    rows = [...new Set(rows)];
    let maxRow = 0;
    rows.forEach( row => { maxRow = row > maxRow ? row : maxRow } );
    let columns = values.map( row => row[1] ); // get the column numbers
    columns = [...new Set(columns)]
    let maxColumn = 0;
    columns.forEach( column => { maxColumn = column > maxColumn ? column : maxColumn } );
    let dbh = [];
    let notes = []; 
    for( let i=0; i<maxRow; i++ ) {
      dbh.push(Array(maxColumn).fill(""));
      notes.push(Array(maxColumn).fill(""));  
      dbh[i].unshift(i+1);  // add row number
    }
    values.forEach( row => {
        let i = row[0]-1;
        let j = row[1];
        dbh[i][j] = row[2];
        //Update the lines below with your formatted cell note column names and N-1 column numbers:
        notes[i][j-1] =
        "ID: "+row[3]+
        "\nDBH: "+row[2];  // End cell note formatting      
      }
    );
    console.log(notes);
    // Add headers
    dbh.unshift(Array(maxColumn).fill(0));
    dbh[0].forEach( (cell,index) => dbh[0][index] = index+1 );
    dbh[0].unshift("Rows & Columns");
    sheet.getRange(1,MY_ROWS_COLUMNS_TEXT,dbh.length,dbh[0].length).setValues(dbh);
    sheet.getRange(2,MY_ROWS_COLUMNS_NBR,notes.length,notes[0].length).setNotes(notes); 
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in test: "+err)
  }
}
```

Comment: Use setNote() just like you use setValue()

Comment: I added the question.

Comment: Did you write the current code?

Comment: No, see the link to the "partial answer".

Comment: Wow, thanks!  I upvoted your answer since it is very helpful.  Would it be possible to "dynamically add other potential data fields"?  If there were 2 other optional fields, it would push the "Rows & Columns" cell to I think 1,6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken the original code and editted it to place the notes for each ID.

Notice I still use my sheet named "Test".

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Test");
    let values = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,4).getValues();  // exclude header
    let rows = values.map( row => row[0] );  // get the row numbers
    rows = [...new Set(rows)];
    let maxRow = 0;
    rows.forEach( row => { maxRow = row > maxRow ? row : maxRow } );
    let columns = values.map( row => row[1] ); // get the column numbers
    columns = [...new Set(columns)]
    let maxColumn = 0;
    columns.forEach( column => { maxColumn = column > maxColumn ? column : maxColumn } );
    let dbh = [];
    let notes = [];  // ***** added *****
    for( let i=0; i<maxRow; i++ ) {
      dbh.push(Array(maxColumn).fill(""));
      notes.push(Array(maxColumn).fill(""));  // ***** added *****
      dbh[i].unshift(i+1);  // add row number
    }
    values.forEach( row => {
        let i = row[0]-1;
        let j = row[1];
        dbh[i][j] = row[2];
        notes[i][j-1] = "ID: "+row[3]+"\n DBH: "+row[2];  // ***** added *****
      }
    );
    console.log(notes);
    // Add headers
    dbh.unshift(Array(maxColumn).fill(0));
    dbh[0].forEach( (cell,index) => dbh[0][index] = index+1 );
    dbh[0].unshift("Rows & Columns");
    sheet.getRange(1,5,dbh.length,dbh[0].length).setValues(dbh);
    sheet.getRange(2,6,notes.length,notes[0].length).setNotes(notes);  // ***** added *****
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in test: "+err)
  }
}
```